# Hosting jQuery Mobile app using Web API

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jquery-mobile

I've put together a very basic tutorial for a jQuery Mobile app with a very basic tutorial using the Web Api with VS 2013 and VB.NET. The Web Api is just for use with my UI within my app as a way to bridge between html and asp.net.  It works perfectly on my development machine but the Web Api part fails when I move it to my hosting service (WinHost).  I assume that there is a web.config entry that will fix this - but, I'm totally lost on this point.  The html/jQuery code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <title>Boilerplate</title> 
    <script>
      var uri = 'api/class1s';
      function formatItem(item) {
        return item.field1;
      }
      function find() {
        var id = $('#prodId').val();
        $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
          .done(function (data) {
            $('#product').text(formatItem(data));
          })
          .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
          });
      }
    </script>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Boilerplate</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content"> 
        <p>Page Body content</p>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="prodId" size="5" />
          <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />
          <p id="product" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer content</h4>
      </div>
      <a href="{dynamic location}" class="fullSiteLink">View Full Site</a>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The web.config is:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" 
        type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"       
        preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

There is also a WebApiConfig:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web.Http

Public Module WebApiConfig
  Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
    ' Web API configuration and services

    ' Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name:="DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )
  End Sub
End Module
```

There is also a class to define the data and a `controller` to populate data and return data via the Web Api.
These should not affect this problem (and work perfectly on my desktop PC).
Otherwise, this is just a standard **VS2013 ASP.Net 4.5.1** project using an empty website with the Web Api option selected.

Is there a way to get this program to work on the hosting service?

Comment: Is there any error that you see?

Comment: Hi Douglas, Thanks for asking but it's fixed now.  It was a setup issue on my hosting service that I simply forgot about.  Even though the site starts with an HTML page, the VB part still requires the site to be configured on the hosting service as an ASP site.

Comment: Nice to hear that. :)